# Can you stampede with an auroch using a wildshape

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape

I'm fairly new at pathfinder so I have no idea how this would work. I know I would be able to communicate with the animal if I'm the same type of animal, but coordinating enough to stampede might be a whole other ball game. And then comes the question if you can stampede with just two or if it has to be more

Answer (score 3):

### You can communicate to other Aurochs while Wild Shaped into one. What you can do with it is up to your RP and GM discretion.

From [Wild Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Wild-Shape-Su-): *{emphasis added}*

> A druid loses her ability to speak while in animal form because she is limited to the sounds that a normal, untrained animal can make, **but she can communicate normally with other animals of the same general grouping** as her new form.

Now a couple important points. You, yourself, cannot Stampede with the Aurochs. Wild Shape acts as [Beast Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape) which does not provide Extraordinary Abilities that are not listed. Also, it takes 3 [Aurochs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/herd-animals/aurochs) to Stampede per the ability itself: *{emphasis added}*

> **A stampede occurs if three or more creatures with stampede** make a trample attack while remaining adjacent to each other. While stampeding, the creatures can trample foes of their size or smaller, and the trample’s save DC increases by +2.

From this, you could definitely (try) to convince 3 or more (other) Aurochs to Stampede on your behalf by communicating the need or playing on their fear. How this interaction is adjudicated is up to your GM. Some GM's may allow you to Stampede with them despite not having the ability RAW (per the [Rule of Cool](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RuleOfCool) *{TVTropes link}*), while others may not let you successfully convince the Aurochs.

---

Also make sure to check out [this question on Wild Shape](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69985/what-do-you-and-do-you-not-inherit-from-your-new-form-when-using-wild-shape-be) for a much more in-depth explanation of the ability by @HeyICanChan.

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

Polymorph effects in general and wild shape in particular don't let you copy just any extraordinary ability; they operate by white-list. And stampede is an extraordinary ability that's not on wild shape's white-list, so you don't get it.

You don't need to coordinate, and you don't need to be the same type of animal. But you do need to have the ability, and that lack is what disqualifies you.

And no, you can't have a stampede of two, because the ability says "three or more".